# SimpleMembershipProvider GetRoleByUserID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles, simplemembership

What is the best way to get user role(s) by user ID? There arent straight way to it? 
System.Web.Security.Roles offers straight way to get currently logged in users roles, but i want my admin user to access others users roles by their id or username.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a username from a userId, for example with

```
((ExtendedMembershipProvider)Membership).GetUserNameFromId(userId)
```

(you could also cast `Membership` to a `SimpleMembershipProvider` as this inherits from  `ExtendedMembershipProvider`).

Then you can use:

- `Roles.GetUsersInRole(roleName)` will list all users in a given role by username.
- `Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName)` will list all role names for a given username

(You can also get a userId from a username, for example with `WebSecurity.GetUserId(userName)` to work with these results).

There is another way to get the userName for a userId, using the UsersContext with the template account model, which is:

```
string username = context.Users.Where(x=>x.userid == userid).FirstOrDefault().UserName;
```

This can be especially useful if you are doing more than one user lookup, or already have the context open.